# Prevent refreshing of activity on orientation change android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation

I am developing an android application where, there i replace fragments on clicks. I have separate designs for landscape and portrait modes. But the problem is, when i change the orientation, the activity refreshes and the button remains unclicked, i tried giving

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

But no use, alse setting it to screensize was not taking the other layout designs, please suggest how to overcome this, by not refreshing the activity on orientation change but still accepting the other layout.

Answer (score 9):

Above API level 12 we need to add screenSize also to prevent refreshing along with orientation.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Comment: Wasted nearly 3 hours for not using the "screenSize". Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use `onSaveInstanceState` to store the state of button or any other state and restore it in `onCreate` using provided `Bundle`.

If you are using a button that is a `CompoundButton` (like `CheckBox`), its state will be retained automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can u give an example?? i am using a normal button btw!

Answer (score 1):

As *Gorski* said , **onSaveInstanceState** & **onViewStateRestored** ( for fragments ) is the way to store state of Fragment or Activity

**onSaveInstanceState** : called when the fragment is paused or stopped

**onViewStateRestored** : called when fragment is comeback

Ex:

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(Keys.CURRENT_OPERATIONS.name(), operations);
        firstCall = true;
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (firstCall)
            operations = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(Keys.CURRENT_OPERATIONS.name());
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    }
```